# Can import the gradle of android app to build in AOSP project

Tags: android-source

I have an android app build by android-studio that use gradle script, now I want to move app to AOSP build system. So how can I import the gradle script and convert to AOSP build (may be Android.bp or Android.mk).
In gradle project have many dependency, android-studio can automatic download this dependency, can I do that in AOSP?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, you probably need to write Andorid.mk manually. By the way, AOSP build system not download dependencies automatically for you. If the dependencies are available in AOSP you no need to download them, just link to them. Otherwise, you need to download them to local directory then use Android.mk to add them to AOSP and linking.

This is an example of Android.mk. In which, the "libs" directory contains the libraries not available in AOSP.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := testapp

LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := com.example.testapp

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled


LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions \
    androidx.appcompat_appcompat \
    androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout \
    androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview \
    androidx.cardview_cardview \
    android-support-v4 \

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    cdi-api \
    zxing-core \
    http \
    httpclient \
    httpcore \

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    cdi-api:libs/cdi-api.jar \
    zxing-core:libs/core-3.3.2.jar \
    http:libs/http-2.2.1.jar \
    httpclient:libs/httpclient-4.2.2.jar \
    httpcore:libs/httpcore-4.2.3.jar \

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```